# Value for URL not loading for onitemclick in listview

Tags: android, listview, webview, xml-parsing

Ok I have been working on this a few days now and have narrowed down my problem to the fact I don't think it is actually getting the node item from the xml file to load the URL.  I'm using a DOM parser to parse the xml file and load into a listview.  I am trying to load the URL from each item into a custom webview activity and if i hardcode a url in place of the stringed url it works perfectly, if i put the stringed url in there it doesn't load the URL value.  Here are the code and classes i'm working with.  Thank you for your help.

xml parser activity

```
 public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
 }
```

listview adaptor class

```
 public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image


    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
    artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_PUB_DATE));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_LINK), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
 }
```

main activity

```
 public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://treymorgan.net/feed";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node 
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_PUB_DATE = "pubDate";
static final String KEY_LINK = "link";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_PUB_DATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUB_DATE));
        map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, WebviewActivity.class);  
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            intent.putExtra( "b", "KEY_LINK");
            startActivity(intent); 



             }

    });
}   
 }
```

Webview Activity
     public class WebviewActivity extends Activity{
      private WebView webview;

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    String KEY_LINK = b.getString("b");

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.setInitialScale(1);
    webview.loadUrl(KEY_LINK);



  }


       }
```

Here is a sample item of the XML i am parsing

```
 <item>
    <title>We’re Building a Feeding Center and Church in Honduras!</title>
    <link>http://treymorgan.net/were-building-a-feeding-center-and-church-in-honduras/</link>
    <comments>http://treymorgan.net/were-building-a-feeding-center-and-church-in-honduras/#comments</comments>
    <pubDate>Fri, 14 Sep 2012 15:47:15 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator>Trey Morgan</dc:creator>
            <category><![CDATA[Honduras]]></category>

    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://treymorgan.net/?p=4640</guid>
    <description><![CDATA[Do you remember this post from two weeks ago about feeding kids in Buen Samaritano?  Marc Tindall needed $6000 to get the feeding center started (which will be used as a church too) &#8230; and this past Monday morning we presented him with the money. WOO HOO!  Thanks to all those who gave.]]></description>
 <wfw:commentRss>http://treymorgan.net/were-building-a-feeding-center-and-church-in-honduras/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
    <slash:comments>1</slash:comments>
<enclosure url="http://treymorgan.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/photo-101-224x300.jpg" length="2854" type="image/jpeg" />  
 </item>
```

Thank you for any help you can give on this

Comment: intent.putExtra( "b", "KEY_LINK"); might be the problem. Shouldn't it be "data.getsong().geturl" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The KEY_LINK url passed to the webView might not be formatted properly.

Try encoding it properly using this first:

```
String urlStr = KEY_LINK;
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();

webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: I'm assuming i load this into my webview activity.  when i did this it gave me a string error for KEY_LINK stating that it wasn't a defined string

Comment: It's not a defined string?  Do this after you obtain the value of KEY_LINK from b.getString("b")

Comment: I thought it wad getting the value of KEY_LINK from the xml.  KEY_LINK is defined as the node link from the xml so I thought it would get that value am I wrong there

Comment: It is geeting it from xml. But then you are putting it into an.intent  in your main activity and calling the webview activity. You are fetching it again there. That's where you need to use my code and encode it properly

Comment: Ok so if I understand it right my main activity code is ok and I just need to use the code u gave in my webview activity to make it work.  I will give this a try in the morning and let u know if it works.  Thanks

Comment: The method loadUrl(String) in the type WebView is not applicable for the arguments (URL), this is what it tells me when i try to implement your code in the webview activity on the loadURL(url) portion of the code.  won't let me compile it to try it

Comment: Unhandled exception type MalformedURLException on the new URL(urlStr);

Comment: Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException on the new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());

Comment: Unhandled exception type MalformedURLException on the uri.toURL();  that happened when i changed to your last change

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17664/discussion-between-anup-cowkur-and-bryan)

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

For the pass string from one activity to the other

**First activity:**

```
Intent indisplay = new Intent(FirstClass.this,SecondClass.class);
indisplay.putExtra("link",your link here);
startActivity(indisplay);
```

**Second activity:**

```
 Intent indispaly = getIntent();
 String url = indispaly.getStringExtra("link");
    // your link from previous activity is stored into the url
```

Comment: that would work great for a hardcoded string, which does work for me just fine.  the problem is if i hardcode the string it won't give the unique url for each item that is clicked and load each items article from the feed it would only give a generic URL.  I need to pass the string that holds the URL for each item to the webview activity and have it load it